# jquery function should hide / show box on page load depending on checked radio value

Tags: jquery, radio-button, onload, checked

I have the following jsfiddle setup:

http://jsfiddle.net/eyTBZ/2/

Basically almost everything works, apart from when the page is loaded and if the value audi is checked then the div engine should be hidden (or if the value is not audi the div should be displayed). Any help in getting this working would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/eyTBZ/5/

I updated these.

1. Used actual values in radio value.
2. click() to change()
3. Called change() at the start to invoke the change effect before doing anything

Comment: Oops just realised, I need to base the checks on id instead of name is that possible?

Comment: No worries got it:  var value = $("input:radio[name$='cartype']:checked").attr('id'); have to use id just beacuse of how the app is structured. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to hide the div to begin with. I would recommend doing this with CSS and showing the div with JS when appropriate, but if you have to use JS, you can do it like this (from your fiddle):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#engine").hide();
    $("input[name$='cartype']").click(function(){
        var value = $(this).attr('id');
        alert(value);
        if(value!='audi') {
            $("#engine").show();
        }else if(value=='audi') {
            $("#engine").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

The reason why it wasn't working before was because your check to see what was selected was inside of the click handler for the radio buttons.

Comment: No problem.  He certainly did more as far as correcting things :)